# How to retrieve variable="value" pairs from m3u string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, m3u

I have m3u file that contain lines like example:

```
#EXTINF:0 $ExtFilter="Viva" group-title="Variedades" tvg-logo="logo/Viva.png" tvg-name="Viva"
```

I run this in PHP with no success:

```
preg_match('/([a-z0-9\-_]+)=\"([a-z0-9\-_\s.]+)\"\s+/i',$str,$matches)
```

I want to get:

```
$matches[0] = $ExtFilter
$matches[1] = Viva
$matches[2] = group-title
$matches[3] = Variedades
$matches[4] = tvg-logo
$matches[5] = logo/Viva.png
$matches[6] = tvg-name
$matches[7] = Viva
```

I try regexp tools (like [this](http://regex101.com/)).

Thank u.

Comment: You only have two capture groups in your regexp, how do you expect it to capture 8 values? Take a look at `preg_match_all()` if you want to match repeatedly.

Comment: Also, note that the capture groups start at 1. `$matches[0]` is the match for the entire regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` to perform multiple matches:

```
preg_match_all('/([\w-]+)="([\w-\s.\/]+)"/i',$str,$matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

It returns the results as a 2-dimensional array -- one dimension is the match, another dimension is the capture groups within the matches. To get them into a single array as in your desired result, use a loop:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    array_push($results, $match[1], $match[2]);
}
print_r($results);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ExtFilter
    [1] => Viva
    [2] => group-title
    [3] => Variedades
    [4] => tvg-logo
    [5] => logo/Viva.png
    [6] => tvg-name
    [7] => Viva
)
```

I simplified your regexp by using `\w` in place of `a-z0-9_`. I also added `/` to the second character set, so that `logo/Viva.png` would match. I got rid of `\s+` at the end, because it prevented the last variable assignment from working.